# "Ректор" — "ректоры", "проректор"  — ?

Tags: орфография

Хотелось бы уточнить, слова "проректор" и "ректор" во множественном числе имеют одинаковое окончание или нет? А то на агитационном, за грамотность населения, плакате в метро было написано: "ректор" — "ректоры", "проректор"  — "проректора". Несколько нелогично.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нормативно: ректор - ректоры, проректор - проректоры. ("Русское словесное ударение")

А в чем, если не секрет, причина интереса именно к *одинаковости* окончания, а не к нормативности как таковой? Меня постановка вопроса несколько смутила.

"Правильно сформулированный вопрос - половина ответа." )))

Comment: В вагоне метро прочитала плакат "Давайте говорить как петербуржцы". Изучить его времени особо не было, но запомнилось что: проректор - проректора, ректор - ректоры. Изумила нелогичность, слова то практически одинаковые. Есть подозрение, что, может, была невнимательна. Поэтому в вопросе и содержался подвох.

Comment: Нт от москвичей, ни от прерербужцев никогда не слышал именно такого варианта. Может, был невнимателен. Если уж по-разному, то скорее уж наоборот: "ректора и проректоры".  
  
Впрочем, с уверенностью могу сказать, что настоящего петербужского произношения давно не осталось. Какие-то остатвки его я слышал от бабушки и её сестер (каждой бог отпустил без малого век), даже непосвященному было слышны особенности их разговоров между собой. 
Московский говор тоже, видимо утерян, но он в большей мере вошел в общелитературный.  

В люом случае, к "ректорам" это никак не относится.

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/985962
Тут дело даже не в произношении(петербургское, московское и тд), это была акция Санкт-Петербургского университета, организации солидной, т.е. заявление на общепринятые нормы. Хотя у них на сайте вижу http://spbu.ru/structure/top-management/prorectors
Совсем запуталась.

Comment: Ушаков, помнится, в гнезде даёт родительный падеж, а не множественное число. Сейчас проверю.

Ну да. Рыба, рыбы; конь, коня...

>это была акция Санкт-Петербургского университета, организации солидной,  
  
Ну дык. Людмила Алексеевна опять хотела как лучше...

Comment: А у кого-нибудь множественное от "проректор" 
можно посмотреть? Я не нашла. Хоть бы одним глазком. А вдруг она права?!

Comment: Она - акция? juki, ну это ж очевидная ошибка исполнителей. У меня в мыслях не было, что сама Вербицкая не знает русского языка.
 
Множественное в словарях обычно не приводится, если оно образцется по соновному правилу (т.е. на Ы/И). Можете посиотреть, как даёт Зарва на грамоте.

Comment: Сдаюсь, "ректоры" и "проректоры". Спасибо.